# RStudio keeps adding `/usr/local/bin` to the front of the PATH variable

Tags: r, path, rstudio

When I run system commands from RStudio using system("..."), I would like RStudio to use a certain version of Python.

When I open RStudio (just by clicking on the icon on a Mac) and set the PATH variables with Sys.setenv(PATH="my_python_path"), this works successfully. To make this the default variable, I tried updating both my ~/.Renviron (Using PATH=...) and ~/.Rprofile (using Sys.setenv("...")) pre-pending the path to the Python I would like to use.

Updating the PATH variables in .Renviron and .Rprofile takes effect, but RStudio nevertheless keeps pre-pending `/usr/local/bin` to the front of the PATH variable, which directs R to the default system Python in that directory. The Python path I specified comes right after that and does not get used.

Is there a way to make RStudio respect the PATH order that I specified in my .Renviron or .Rprofile?

Comment: That's a very short path you are using.  Wouldn't it be safer to prepend `my_python_path` to the existing one, rather the wiping it out completely?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm actually doing in practice. Just didn't include that in the question

Comment: I'm not seeing the behaviour you're describing.  If I run `system("printenv PATH")` I see the same path as I get from `Sys.getenv("PATH")`.  Maybe you need to upgrade RStudio (I'm using 1.4.1103), or maybe something else is going on.

Comment: Yes, that's the behavior I get as well. My problem arises from the fact that if I specify a PATH in my ~/.Rprofile or ~/.Renviron file, RStudio pre-prends `/usr/local/bin` to my PATH, which makes RStudio use a different Python (the one in `/usr/local/bin`) from what I specified

Comment: It seems to be related to Mac OS GUI apps by default inheriting system default PATHs like here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/how-to-set-path-for-finder-launched-applications

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it's clear that it's not RStudio messing up the path, it's Finder.  RStudio does modify the path, but it puts its entries after the existing ones.  When I put this code in my `~/.Rprofile` file:

```
print(Sys.getenv("PATH"))
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste("foobar", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":"))
```

I see this printed:

```
[1] "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

That's the PATH Finder is setting.  Then in the R session, when I run `Sys.getenv("PATH")` I see

```
[1] "foobar:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:
/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local
/git/bin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/postback"
```

showing the additions RStudio (or some code in R run after `.Rprofile`) has made to the end of the path.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm seeing. So I'm wondering, is there a way to prepend to the PATH just for RStudio, so that my specified addition to the PATH is the first one in the PATH?

Comment: Or is the only solution to update the PATH for all Mac OS GUI Finder launched applications (not ideal in my use case)?

Comment: My example prepended "foobar" to the path.  It was first in the path at the end.  What else do you want?

Comment: I want foobar added in front of the path automatically every time I run RStudio. I thought adding foobar to the ~/.Renviron or ~/.Rprofile file would do this, but usr/bin/local is still first.

Comment: I don't want to have to type `Sys.setenv(PATH=paste("foobar", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":"))` every time manually when I start RStudio

Comment: That's not what I saw.  I put those lines in `~/.Rprofile`, and foobar ended up first in the path in RStudio.  You are obviously doing something different, but it's not clear what.

Comment: I'd suggest adding `print()` commands before and after your modification to `~/.Rprofile` to make sure it's being executed and doing what you want it to do.

Comment: Are you launching RStudio from Mac Launchpad/Spotlight? If I launch RStudio from the terminal, it uses ~/.Rprofile and ~/.Renviron. and I get the behavior you're describing. If I launch RStudio from Launchpad/Spotlight, ~/.Rprofile and ~/.Renviron takes effect, but my Mac still prepends `usr/bin/local` to the front

Comment: I normally launch it from the dock, but I just tried from Launchpad, and I see the same as if I launch from the dock.  What you're describing makes no sense:  once .Rprofile is executed, there's no opportunity for macOS to modify the path again.  If it looks okay when you print it at the end of .Rprofile, it should be okay in that session until **you** modify it.